# Unable to deploy azure function app using pipeline.yml file

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have multiple .net mvc apps and 1 .net azure function app in our solution. I have a azure-pipeline.yml file for deployment. Mvc apps goes to app services and Function app goes to azure function.

Now when I run the pipeline on azure devops, it deploys webapps to respective app service but it fails to deploy the azure function with the error:

> ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\a**\FunctionApp.zip
> Check if the package
> mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a
> previous stage and downloaded in the current job. Finishing:
> AzureFunctionApp

But I can see FunctionApp.zip in build artifacts.

Here is my yml:

```
trigger:
- master
- feature/*
- hotfix/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  isMaster: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  isDeployableBranch: $[eq(variables.isMaster, true)]

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and Test Package
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Test_Publish
    displayName: Build_Test_Publish
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
      displayName: 'Install Visual Studio Test Platform'
      inputs:
        packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
        versionSelector: 'latestStable'

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: './'
        externalFeedCredentials: 'Telerik NuGet'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build Solution'
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=$(isDeployableBranch) /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isDeployableBranch, true))
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isDeployableBranch, true))
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWebApp1
    displayName: Deploy Web App 1
    environment: 'PROD'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
              
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'MyResourcegroup'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: 'webapp1'
              packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/WebApp1.zip'

  - deployment: DeployWebApp2
    displayName: Deploy Web App 2
    environment: 'PROD'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
              
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'MyResourceGroup'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: 'webapp2-motionkinetic'
              packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/WebApp2.zip'

  
  - deployment: DeployFunction
    displayName: Deploy Function
    environment: 'PROD'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1 
            inputs:
               azureSubscription: 'MyResourceGroup'
               appType: functionApp
               appName: 'MyFunction'
               package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/FunctionApp.zip'
```

I think the issue is in the yml file itself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add an inline script step to check if the expected file exists where you think it exists?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


stages:
  - stage: C
    displayName: C
    jobs:
    - job: xxx
      displayName: xxxOfC
      steps:
      - task: VSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: '**\*.sln'
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            mkdir AF
            mkdir MVC1
            mkdir MVC2
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/FunctionAppAndMVC/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AF'
        displayName: Copy Files to AF
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC1/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC1'
        displayName: Copy Files to MVC1(1)
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC1/wwwroot'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC1'
        displayName: Copy Files to MVC1(2)
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC2'
        displayName: Copy Files to MVC2(1)
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC2/wwwroot'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC2'
        displayName: Copy Files to MVC2(2)
      
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AF'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/FunctionApp.zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true
        displayName: Archive Azure Function Files
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC1'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MVC1.zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true
        displayName: Archive MVC1 Files
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MVC2'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MVC2.zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true
        displayName: Archive MVC2 Files
      
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
        displayName: Publish Artifact
  - stage: D
    displayName: Deploy
    jobs:
    - job: xxx
      displayName: xxxOfD
      steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          downloadType: 'single'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
      - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'testbowman_in_AAD'
          appType: 'functionApp'
          appName: 'testbowman'
          package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/AF.zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'xxx'
          appType: 'webApp'
          appName: 'xxx'
          package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/MVC1.zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'xxx'
          appType: 'webApp'
          appName: 'xxx'
          package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/MVC2.zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Original Answer:**

I don't see the FunctionApp.zip before the deploy stage.

Seems no one archived files as 'FunctionApp.zip'(From your YAML I can't see it).

Below YAML will work:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
  - stage: C
    displayName: C
    jobs:
    - job: xxx
      displayName: xxxOfC
      steps:
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/FunctionApp.zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
  - stage: D
    displayName: Deploy
    jobs:
    - job: xxx
      displayName: xxxOfD
      steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          downloadType: 'single'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
      - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'testbowman_in_AAD'
          appType: 'functionApp'
          appName: 'testbowman'
          package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, had to do small tweaks in your answer but indeed that was the problem.

Comment: So I thought that the tweaks I made actually worked but they haven't. So actually I have two other mvc projects (part of the same solution) as well that I want to deploy via same yml. The archive step actually archive whole solution and deploy all projects to each app service and azure function. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Ask The key is 'path', the deploy task always based on some specific path, If you need a sample, please let me know.

Comment: that would be really helpful if you can share the sample

Comment: @Ask I have update the answer, just to provide an idea for your reference.

Comment: @Ask Do you still have the problem now?